# $B$ finite over $A$ implies $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ finitely generated as $A_{\mathfrak{q}}$-algebra

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $f\colon A\longrightarrow B$ be a finite algebra (B is finite as $A$-module) and let $\mathfrak{p}\in\mathsf{Spec} \, B$ and denote $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})=\mathfrak{q}$. Is it true that $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is finitely generated as $A_{\mathfrak{q}}$-algebra?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty in commutative algebra, but I guess that if $\{m_1,\dotso,m_n\}\subset B$ is a set of generators for $B$ as an $A$-module, then $\{\frac{m_1}{1},\dotso,\frac{m_n}{1}\}$ is a set of generators for $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ as an $A_{\mathfrak{q}}$-module. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can also consider $A=K[X^2,X^3]$, $B=K[X]$ and $P=(X)$. The very same element $\frac{1}{X+1}$ is not integral over $A$, so $A_p\subset B_q$ is not finite.

Comment: I'm trying to check that it is finitely generated(quotient of a polynomial ring) not finite.